# Databricks: Adding path to table from csv

Tags: sql, csv, databricks

In databricks I have several CSV files that I need to load. I would like to add a column to my table with the file path, but I can't seem to find that option

My data is structured with

```
FileStore/subfolders/DATE01/filenameA.csv
FileStore/subfolders/DATE01/filenameB.csv
FileStore/subfolders/DATE02/filenameA.csv
FileStore/subfolders/DATE02/filenameB.csv
```

I'm using this SQL function in databricks, as this can loop through all the dates and add all filenameA into clevertablenameA, and all filenameB into clevertablenameB etc.

```
DROP view  IF EXISTS clevertablenameA;
create temporary view clevertablenameA
USING csv
OPTIONS (path "dbfs:/FileStore/subfolders/*/filenameA.csv", header = true)
```

My desired outcome is something like this

```
col1 | col2|....| path
data | data|....| dbfs:/FileStore/subfolders/DATE02/filenameA.csv
data | data|....| dbfs:/FileStore/subfolders/DATE02/filenameA.csv
data | data|....| dbfs:/FileStore/subfolders/DATE02/filenameA.csv
```

Is there a clever option, or should I load my data another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `input_file_name()` could be used to retrieve the file name **while reading**.

```sql
SELECT *, input_file_name() as path FROM clevertablenameA
```

Note that this does not add a column to the view and merely returns the name of the file being read.

Refer to below link for more information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions/input_file_name

Alternatively you could try reading the files in a pyspark/scala cell and add the file name using the same function using the `.withColumn("path", input_file_name())` function and then create the view on top of it.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you. Have a +1 and an extra bun for chrismas